# License for using Salesforce CLI?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

As a customer of Salesforce, is there further license need of any kind to use the Salesforce'c CLI?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Salesforce DX with these standard user licenses: Salesforce, Salesforce Platform, and Developer.

[documentation link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm)